# A list and replaces its elements with values from the dictionary with the help of keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, data-science

```py
my_dict    = {'blue': '0000FF', 'green': '00FF00', 'yellow': 'FFFF00', 'red': 'FF0000', 'white': 'FFFFFF', 'black': '000000'}

my_list    = ['blue', 'white', 'black', 'yellow', 'green', 'red']
```

I want to replace items in my_list with keys from my_dict, something like...

```py
my_list    =['0000FF','00FF00','FFFF00','FF0000','FFFFFF','000000']
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
my_new_list = [my_dict[item] for item in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. This will change or replace the elements from the same list (`my_list`) and not create a new list:

```py
for i in range(len(my_list)):
  my_list[i] = my_dict[my_list[i]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to map and cast to list, which it is better preformance looping variations:

```
my_list = list(map(my_dict.get,my_list))
```